# ORA-00600 argument description

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

I am experiencing several ORA-00600 error events, presumably during exceptionally high I/O. Does anyone know where I can lookup the meaning of the following arguments for `ktspfmdb:objdchk_kcbnew_3`? I.e. what does `13`, `873730` and `4` stand for?

```
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [ktspfmdb:objdchk_kcbnew_3], [13], [873730], [4], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
```

Comment: Use the ORA-600 lookup tool on the Oracle support site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are facing a bug. You need to gather more information using RDA in order to perform an in-depth analysis.

These are known bugs related to your ORA-600 message.

```
10043021    11.2.0.4, 12.1.0.1  ORA-600 [kcbnew_3] after select / analyze on RECYCLEBIN object

17586955    11.2.0.4.4, 11.2.0.4.BP11   ORA-600 [ktspfmdb:objdchk_kcbnew_3] in RAC

12747437    11.2.0.3.8, 11.2.0.3.BP21, 11.2.0.4, 12.1.0.1   ORA-600 [ktspfmdb:objdchk_kcbnew_3] after purging single consumer queue table

12323180    11.2.0.2.7, 11.2.0.2.BP17, 11.2.0.3, 12.1.0.1   ORA-600 [ktspfmdb:objdchk_kcbnew_3] due to re-used block read into cache

11902008    11.2.0.4, 12.1.0.1  SMON may crash with ORA-600 [kcbgcur_3] or ORA-600 [kcbnew_3] during Transaction recovery

10137834    11.2.0.2    ORA-600 running DBMS_XDB.MOVEXDB_TABLESPACE

9456964     11.2.0.2    OERI[kcbnew_3] after shrinking an IOT and reusing the blocks freed by shrink
```

Look if any of the above descriptions matches your case.

But the short answer would be to open a Service Request with Oracle Support.

Comment: Thanks for listing related bugs. Issue 17586955 sounds relevant for us. I'll give an update after we tracked down this problem...

Answer (score 1):

https://support.oracle.com, with a valid support contract. In most cases, even there you will not find the meaning of the arguments.

Of course, with access to the source code (e.g Oracle Support employees), one can find the meaning of these arguments, as demonstrated in the Oracle DSI401e course, with a case study.